# Launch unity from version control

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, github

I know this might sound super basic to someone, but I do not understand how to lauch project as this https://github.com/TobiahZ/CollectThemAll (Project is not mine just googled for sample project). When I open unity and try to open an existing project, in the category that I cloned repo it does not find the file to open the project.

So far Googling by myself did not give me much answers, so I am trying here. I found numerous sources saying enable projects edtior version control to Visible meta files, but when I push my project others cant open it also, maybe we are missing something.

Comment: @Draco18s that's wrong. You never should push the *.sln and *.csproj to a repository. It's generated as soon as you open/build the project. See e.g. https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore

Comment: @zerocludo what do you mean by `cannot open it`? Are you getting any errors/warnings? In general you clone a repo, open Unity and select the `root folder` of the project (in this case that would be `/.../CollectThemAll`. Alternatively if you have a Scene already it should also work if you double click on the Scene directly.